# Flask - POST request returns only one item

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask, sqlite

I've User and Alarm table in my database. The Alarm table related with the User.

The app handling to all authentications with the API views.

**Problem**

When POST request succeed the controller doesn't return all items in the database. It returns only one.

I will write here the controller codes these takes control of actions after the login succeed

**I tried this**

```
login_user(user)

for item in user.alarm:
    return jsonify({
        "id": item.id,
        "dovizAdi": item.dovizAdi,
        "mevcutDeger": item.mevcutDeger,
        "beklenenDeger": item.beklenenDeger,
        "oranTuru": item.oranTuru,
        "tarih": item.tarih
    })
```

returns only one item

```
{
  "beklenenDeger": "1.56", 
  "dovizAdi": "ons", 
  "id": 1, 
  "mevcutDeger": "1.54", 
  "oranTuru": "buying", 
  "tarih": null
}
```

**I tried this**

```
result = jsonify(str(user.alarm.all()))
return result
```

returns all item but I can't get their values.

```
"[<Alarm u'ons'>, <Alarm u'ceyrek-altin'>]"
```

I've learned json implementation my previous project mongodb. I think I don't unserstand how json works with sql or missed some important thing in the theory. For loop statement that first example I did shouldn't be return the right results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you are returning in for loop instead of collecting data

```
result = []
for item in user.alarm:
    result.append({
        "id": item.id,
        "dovizAdi": item.dovizAdi,
        "mevcutDeger": item.mevcutDeger,
        "beklenenDeger": item.beklenenDeger,
        "oranTuru": item.oranTuru,
        "tarih": item.tarih
    })
return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: Thank for your help. It returned error. It was so close. 

result = '[{}]'.format(', '.join(result))   TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Response found

Comment: @oyilmaztekin are you sure you pasted my code exactly the way I provided?

Comment: The code is wrong, although the approach is along the right lines. You shouldn't call jsonify on the elements in the list, and you definitely shouldn't be manually wrapping them with braces via string formatting at the end; instead, add the Python dicts themselves into the result array, then call jsonify on the whole thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. It will be much more pythonic)) Fixed. Thanks

Comment: @oyilmaztekin read updated asnwer. With suggestion from DanielRoseman.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks to you @DanielRoseman and you Sardorbek.

By the way the last code and previous are both working well.I guess I figured out what I don't undestand with your help. I will be trying to learn append object in python.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call str on the query results.

```
result = jsonify(user.alarm.all())
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried this. TypeError: <Alarm u'ons'> is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

`user.alarm.all()` will return queryset.
You can convert it to list and then serialize it to json
Try this:

```
result = jsonify(list(user.alarm.all()))
```

Comment: List function does not work well. It returns TypeError that "it is not JSON serializable" Even it was worked I still won't be access values of list item.